# iOS : Scrollview and Autolayout, second view not extending

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

When I first learned Autolayout, things where not too bad as you only had 1 width to cope with.  I am struggling to get a Scrollview to grow depending on device (width) and its content equally.  The scrollview has paging on so a StackView is not possible I believe.

The current issue is the first view grows to the right width (I believe its down to the centerX), however the overall content size of the scrollview is not large enough (iPhone 6) and the secondView is only 320 wide.

I could do this in code but I am sure you don't need to.

I have tried quite a few options like saying greater than on the width

[image]

Comment: well you don't need center on View1, once you have leading and width you don't need center or vice versa, you are also setting the width to 320, where iPhone 6 is 375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understood your question, you want autoresize for views inside scrollview. So, instead of creating width constraint, you should add '**equal width constraint**' to your target view:

[image]

second step

[image]

if scrollview tells you, that it has ambiguous  scrollable content, add bottom constraint for it.

Basically, if you need autolayout inside scroll view, you should provide contentView and setup it with trailing, leading, top, bottom contstaint to scroll view:

[image]

This trick allow you to add another  object inside scrollview and use autolayout easily.

Hope this helps